# how to read a particular column or a row from a text file in c++

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, multidimensional-array, text-files

If a text file contains many rows and columns (say `100*100`). How can I pick up a particular column and read all the values in that column and then corresponding to a particular value in that column, I need to read all the values in that row. Can anyone help please.

Regards.

Comment: As @shipr mentions, your question is unclear (what exactly is in the file?)  However, you can seek to a specific point in a file.  The challenge would be to know how far into the file to seek to obtain a given row/column.  However, if it is a fixed format, you can determine this with a few trials (i.e. a character is a byte, for most text files, and end of line is going to have some encoding, under windows it is likely CR,LF, that you will have to adjust your offsets for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear.  Do you mean columns of characters (the Nth character in a row), of numbers ("2 3 0 9 45 223 93 1" being eight columns, or something else?

In any case, you can only read the file by rows, so to extract a certain column it will be necessary to read the file into memory first, storing the data in strings.  Then in each string, get the column values you are looking for.  When you find it, the string in which you found it will be the row you want.